# Convert multiple rows into single row based on condition

Tags: teradata

Following is the input from my table .

```
Name     Starttime            Endtime
ABC      2019-06-12 01:52:46  2019-06-12 02:52:46
DEF      2019-06-12 02:52:46  2019-06-12 03:52:46
GHI      2019-06-12 03:52:46  2019-06-12 04:52:46
JKL      2019-06-12 04:52:46  2019-06-12 05:52:46
ABC      2019-06-11 01:22:46  2019-06-11 02:22:46
DEF      2019-06-11 02:22:46  2019-06-11 03:22:46
GHI      2019-06-11 03:22:46  2019-06-11 04:22:46
JKL      2019-06-11 04:22:46  2019-06-11 05:22:46
```

Desired Output

```
DATE        STARTTIME            ENDTIME
2019-06-12  2019-06-12 01:52:46  2019-06-12 03:52:46
```

The startime of my output is the start time of the name 'ABC' and the endtime is the end time of the name 'DEF'. The most recent data needs to be fetched. I only require the names ABC and DEF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need some conditional aggregation:

`max(case when name = 'ABC' then StartTime else null end) as StartTime,
max(Case when name = 'DEF' the EndTime else null end) as EndTime`